# How to map two rxjs streams?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two async streams:

```
users = new Subject<User[]>();
groups$ = new Subject<Rights>();
mapped$ = new Subject();
```

I want to map first stream with value from the second.
Using imperative way I do this like:

```
users.foreach((user: User => {
    user.value = groups.find((g) => g.user == user.id)?.value
});
```

How to do that using RXJS to get mapped result in `mapped$`?

Comment: Probably you can use mergeMap or forkJoin

Comment: Why are you using streams for this? Doesn't look like you need streams, arrays/lists will do just fine, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combineLatest` to emit when either `users$` or `groups$` emits, then `map` to add the group to each user:

```
combineLatest([users$, groups$]).pipe(
  map(([users, groups]) => users.map(user => {
    user.value = groups.find(g => g.user == user.id)?.value
    return user
  }))
)
```